# Measure Accuracy in Hierarchical Clustering (Single link) in R

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

How can I measure accuracy in Hierarchical Clustering (Single link) in R with 2 Clusters ?
Here is my code:

```
> dcdata = read.csv("kkk.txt")
> target = dcdata[,3]
> dcdata = dcdata [,1:2]
> d = dist(dcdata)
> hc_single = hclust(d,method="single")
> plot(hc_single)
> clusters =cutree(hc_single, k=2)
> print(clusters)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "accuracy"? For clustering there is not really a correct answer.

Comment: I have a project to finish and this is one of the questions, the only thing i could find about accuracy is in classification with confusion matrix, which makes sense but in clustering there is nothing thats why i asked here

Comment: Hey I can see that you do k=2, this is something like a binary classification then. and you want to see how much it agrees with target. meaning, in each of the clusters, do you see a segregation of the two different labels in target?

Comment: what do you mean segregation? How can I achieve this? I am still a newbie on this

Comment: See below for an example... Basically you want to see in each cluster, do you have close to 100% of one type of target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accuracy is not the most accurate term, but I guess you want to see whether the hierarchical clustering gives you clusters or groups that coincide with your labels. For example, I use the iris dataset, and use setosa vs others as target:

```
data = iris
target = ifelse(data$Species=="setosa","setosa","others")
table(target)
others setosa 
   100     50

data = data[,1:4]
d = dist(data)
hc_single = hclust(d,method="single")
plot(hc_single)
```

[image]

Seems like they are two major clusters. Now we try to see how the target are distributed:

```
library(dendextend)
dend <- as.dendrogram(hc_single)
COLS = c("turquoise","orange")
names(COLS) = unique(target)
dend <- color_labels(dend, col = COLS[target[labels(dend)]])
plot(dend)
```

[image]

Now like what you did, we get the clusters,

```
clusters =cutree(hc_single, k=2)
table(clusters,target)

            target
    clusters others setosa
           1      0     50
           2    100      0
```

You get an almost perfect separation. All the data points in cluster 1 are setosa and all in cluster 2 are not setosa. So you can think of it as like 100% accuracy but I would be careful about using the term.

You can roughly calculate the coincidence like this:

```
Majority_class = tapply(factor(target),clusters,function(i)names(sort(table(i)))[2])
```

This tells you for each cluster, which is the majority class. And from there we see how much this agrees with the actual labels.

```
mean(Majority_class[clusters] == target)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time, I got it now and actually managed to figure it out. I used this code and it gave me the correct results: `> cm = as.matrix(table(Actual = target, Predicted = clusters)) > accuracy = sum(diag(cm)) / sum(cm) > print(accuracy)` Thank you!