# For hierarchical clustering, how to find the “center” in each cluster in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, centroid

I would like to know the central point of each cluster by the hierarchical clustering method in software R. Below the codes I obtained to find the clusters, now I would like to know the central point of each one.
    Thank you!

```
library (readxl)
B1 <- read_excel ("C: / Users / Jovani / Google Drive / Google Drive PC / Work / Clustering /test.xlsx")
> A<-scale (B1)
> d<-dist(A)
> fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average")
> plot(fit.average,hang=-1,cex=.8,main="Average Linkage Clustering")
> clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k=5)
> plot(fit.average)
> rect.hclust(fit.average,k=5)
```

[image]

```
graphic image
> library (factoextra)
> fviz_cluster (list (data = A, cluster = clusters))
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm good question. you can take the mean of all the members in the cluster? Even though you use hclust with "average", unlike kmeans, the clustering is not done with a center..

Comment: Yes, I can calculate the mean, but I would like to find the distance between the centroid of cluster 1 and all observations of the cluster 1? It's possible?

Comment: i write something below, see whether it works for you. Not very clear what you would like to do

Comment: Thank you very much!. But I would like to know what the central points are specifically, and what is the distance from the elements of each cluster to the central point. Example: In cluster 5, I have element 7, 8, 9 and 10 (see figure above) , and I would like to know the distance between each of these elements and the central point of cluster 5. Thanks again.

Comment: I believe it would be an option. I will test it, could you please provide me with the codes to do this?

Comment: StuipWolf, Do you know how to do this that you mentioned via code? Thanksss

Comment: Hey, to combine two matrices, you use the command rbind. Your question says find the centre and I have answered that. If you have a separate issue, please post it as a separate question with a reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate what is approximately the centre by aggregating the means. First simulate some data and cluster:

```
set.seed(123)
A<-matrix(rnorm(400),20,20)
d<-dist(A)
fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average")
clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k=5)
```

You get the mean for each variable in each cluster:

```
cluster_center = aggregate(A,list(cluster=clusters),mean)
 cluster_center[,1:4]
  cluster         V1          V2         V3
1       1 -0.2665343 -0.51417960  0.9057041
2       2  0.1564301  0.07446027 -0.3107495
3       3 -0.8689263 -0.11354894 -0.1253569
4       4  0.7617505 -0.05818998  0.1162087
5       5  1.7869131  0.68864025  1.5164706
```

Distance between each center is:

```
dist(cluster_center[,-1])


         1        2        3        4
2 3.807366                           
3 4.868791 4.270748                  
4 4.334099 3.897603 4.976135         
5 6.629191 5.515162 6.876456 6.548609
```

Comment: @JSouza see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403510/a-user-uses-comments-to-draw-my-attention-to-the-new-questions-he-posts-what-sh

Comment: I understand you might need help with some pressing problems. It's better to improve your question or offer a bounty so that it gains more attention

Comment: I apologize, thank you for letting me know. I saw a post that answered something similar (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60019942/measure-accuracy-in-hierarchical-clustering-single-link-in-r), so I thought you could help me. Offer a bounty that you said, what do you mean? Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. You can see https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: Ah now I understand. Thanks StupidWolf for the clarifications and the message sent.